# How do you find which drive is failing in RAID10 RAIDXpert2 on Windows 11

Tags: raid, windows-11, intel-matrix-storage

I had few occurrences when my PC would take very long time to start. About 5 times over last 6 months. It would be stuck *before* POST for 20 min for example. No reboot, reset and pulling power cord out of PSU would help.

I have a SSD for C: and HDD RAID10 x 4 Seagate 2TB drives using mobo Intel RAIDXpert2.

It wasnt too bad but once there were some files lost which I had to fix with `chkdsk`.

And today I had a work meeting and couldnt start it. So I decided to finally look into it.

My ASUS mobo displays `A2` code while it is hang. Apparently it is something to do with IDE. So I disconnected all 4 HDDs and it worked without a hitch.

So I just connected the HDDs back, it went to POST ok, Windows load took about 4 min (blue squares with rolling waiting icon).

RAIDXpert2 "app" shows no errors and no rebuilds on the array. There are some minor errors in the log but I dont know whether they are from today or 2 yrs ago as there is no date

I cant go disconnecting drives one by one to find out because it is very intermittent and it might take months to find out, also disconnecting a drive would probably push it to rebuild later on which takes 20 hrs..

Is there a way to **actively** investigate it? A diagnostic tool, a detailed and timestamped log?
[image]

Comment: Oh good. It failed during work hours (before it was only problem to wakeup from hibernation), I disconnected the one which was mounted vertically (the other 3 are horizontal) and it worked. So I found it. I wonder if vertical position killed it